# latexdiff messes up equations and eqnarray

Tags: equations, latexdiff, eqnarray

I am using latexdiff(1.3.0) to track some changes in a latex file. My problem is that, for some eqnarray part of the file which does not change between the two versions, such as

```
 \begin{eqnarray}
 \delta Z_e|_{G_\mu}&=& \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(0)}-\frac{1}{2}\Delta r\, ,\\
 \delta Z_e|_{G_\mu}&=&\delta Z_e|_{\alpha(m_Z)}-\frac{1}{2}\left(-  \frac{c_W^2}{ s_W^2}\Delta \rho + \Delta r_{\rm rem}\right)\, ,\\
 \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(\mz)}&=& \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(0)}-\frac{1}{2}\Delta\alpha(\mz^2)\,,
 \label{alphaGmucond}
 \end{eqnarray}
```

I get this in the diff

```
 \begin{eqnarray}
 \delta Z_e|_{G_\mu}&=& \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(0)}-\frac{1}{2}\Delta r\, ,\\
 \delta Z_e|_{G_\mu}&=&\delta Z_e|_{\alpha(m_Z)}-\frac{1}{2}\left(-  \frac{c_W^2}{ s_W^2}\Delta \rho + \Delta r_{\rm rem}\right)\, ,\\
 \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(\mz)}&=& \delta Z_e|_{\alpha(0)}-\frac{1}{2}\Delta\alpha(\mz^2)\,,
 \label{alphaGmucond}
 \end{equation}
```

This happens in quite some places, thus I would like to know if there is a solution other than 'fix it by hand'...
Thanks a lot!

Cheers,

Marco

Comment: Never, ever, use `eqnarray`.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please, can you add your complete compilable code? There are many reasons: for example what is \mz? A macro?

Comment: The question cannot be answered as is, as it depends on the context in the file. Try to construct a minimal but complete example, and then submit it on the latexdiff github page as a bug report: https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/